# Custom Swing-Panels showing up just a little moment

Tags: java, swing

In my class `BlindSettings` which extends JFrame I have a code-fragment that adds `BlindPanels` dynamically (`BlindPanels` are a sort of custom `JPanel`). The problem is, when I call the `BlindSettings` directly from my main-method, everything works fine, but if I call the same class in the order of my program (like first the `Welcome` screen, then the `MainSettings` screen and then the `BlindSettings`), this panels are shown just a very little moment like (1/10 seconds). So I see the requested panels for a moment, but then they disappear automatically.

The part where I add this panels is following

```
for(int i=0; i<=18; i++){
    BlindPanel panel = new BlindPanel(i, blindGround.getWidth(), blindGround.getHeight(), fontNormal2);
    blindGround.add(panel);
}
```

What could cause this? There are no external parameters or other external stuff that have influence on the building of the GUI, it's just adding GUI-Stuff to a JFrame.

(I'm not sure what code I should post here, because the two classes `BlindSettings` and `BlindPanel` are +/- big.)

Comment: You should check that the staff is added correctly.

Comment: *"What could cause this?"*  One primary cause is 'the code'.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).